# PostgreSQL update column based on the same column

Tags: postgresql

I would like to update a column in a table that contains names with several characters added as suffix. Is it possible to remove these characters from this specific column in some way as there is not any other condition?

For example I have got names such as

**Joe Doe Nm** and I want to update it to **Joe Doe**

**John Crow Nkk** and update it to **John Crow**

**George Stavrou_Ngf** and same as above (**George Stavrou**)

and similar style regarding names.

Regards

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking text tables. ([edit] your question - do **not** put code or additional information in comments)

Comment: How exactly do you want to distinguish between a name and a suffix? What is the precise rule for "similar style"? Something like "*Anything that is at the end of the input string, starts with the letter `N`, is two or three letters long, and is preceded by a space or underscore, is considered to be a suffix*"?

Comment: Hello! I managed to fix it somehow by specifying a subquery and query for each specific name                                                                                                       
UPDATE table1                                                                                                                SET name='George Stavrou'                                                                                                WHERE id IN (select id from table1 where name LIKE 'George Stavrou%')                                   Regards